# Por que devemos preferir composição ao invés de herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, engenharia-de-software, composição, princípio-liskov

Desde a popularização da orientação a objetos nos anos 90 eu ouço falar que a composição deve ser preferida antes de se criar hierarquia de tipos. Mas talvez o conceito mais importante da orientação a objetos é a herança.

Diz-se que só pode usar herança quando o tipo **é um** tipo que ele herda, que possa haver uma substituição direta de um pelo outro ([princípio da substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov)). E a composição deve ser usada quando o um tipo **tem um** outro tipo.

**Por que** isto é necessário ou mais vantajoso? Dá a impressão que é uma falha da orientação a objeto.

É possível então usar só a composição sem grandes desvantagens?

Existe alguma forma de perceber claramente quando a herança é melhor?

Comment: Me desculpem pela falha, já havia algo que responde a essência do eu queria.