# Classe mãe assume atributos da filha?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, herança

Criei duas classes, `Funcionário` e `Assistente`.

Funcionário possui: `nome`, `idade`, `salario` e o `metodo` `exibirDados()`;

`Assistente` sobrescreve este método, e possui também o atributo `matricula`.

Eu fiz a herança e sobrescrevi o método na classe `Assistente` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Assistente extends Funcionario{

protected int matricula;

public int getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public Assistente(String nome, int idade, int salario, int matricula) {
    super(nome, idade, salario);
    this.matricula = matricula;
    
}

public void exibirDados(Funcionario funcionario) {
    System.out.println("Nome = "+ funcionario.getNome()+" Matrícula: "+ funcionario.getMatricula)
}
```

}

O que eu esperava que acontecesse fosse que ao se criar a herança, mesmo que a classe `Funcionario` não tivesse esse atributo `matricula`, o compilador pudesse "compreender" que está nas classes filhas. No entanto, o compilador não reconhece o método de *get* que eu implementei ali. Como fazer com que a classe mãe "assuma" um atributo que está declarado em uma classe filha?

Vou colocar aqui também o código que fiz para a classe `Funcionario`:

```
public class Funcionario {
String nome;
int idade;
int salario;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}
public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}

public int getSalario() {
    return salario;
}
public void setSalario(int salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}



public Funcionario(String nome, int idade, int salario ){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
    this.salario = salario;

    
}


public void exibirDados(Funcionario funcionario) {
    System.out.println("Nome = "+ funcionario.getNome()+" | Idade = "+ funcionario.getIdade()+" | Salario = "+ funcionario.getSalario());
}
```

}

Além de `Funcionario` e `Assistente`, me foi pedido para criar classes-filhas de `Assistente` (assistente técnico e administrativo), onde eu devo modificar o valor do salário deles em algumas condições.

Comment: A noção de herança é de especialização, no sentido da classe base para a classe derivada e não o contrário. `Assistente` *extends* `Funcionario` e não o contrário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comece lendo [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Eu não sei o que você quer dizer com "assume", o termo não costuma ser usado no assunto. Mas imagino o que é.

Bem a grosso modo, quando você cria uma herança de uma classe você está falando para o compilador dar um ^C e ^V por você.

Tudo que tem na classe base terá na classe derivada.

O compilador não deixará tudo ser acessado dentro da classe derivada, mas tudo está lá.

Outro ponto é que quando falo que tudo está lá, no objeto é só o [estado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311349/101), ou seja, os valores dos campos (todos eles, até os que não estão escritos no código mas vieram por herança). [Dados da classe que são globais para todos os objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17018/101) e os métodos em si só existem uma vez, não tem porque copiar, e sempre está para todos objetos daquele tipo, inclusive os de tipos derivados. Se eles podem ser acessados dali ou se eles não podem porque foi dito que tem uma versão mais adequada dele nem um determinado contexto é outra questão, e isso vai depender do [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154421/101).

Essa última parte parece ter entendido.

Um campo com [visibilidade privada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165476/101) estará no objeto de uma classe derivada, mas não poderá ser acesso diretamente dentro dessa nova classe. Poderá ser acessado por um método da classe base que esteja disponível na classe derivada.

Classes base não devem ter conhecimento das classes derivadas. O mecanismo de herança foi criado justamente para isto, se não for para fazer assim não precisa de herança, resolva como uma coisa só.

Então não, `Funcionario` não deve saber nada que está presente em `Assistente`, e se estiver por erro conceitual, você terá que fazer a classe `Funcionario` tratar disso manualmente, até por ser um erro o compilador não vai te ajudar, por isso nem tente se não souber muito o que está fazendo e souber que tem uma exceção para lidar aí, não parece ser o caso.

Não vou entrar no mérito que [essa herança não costuma ser ideal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101), porque geralmente um `Assistente` é só um [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327842/101) de [um `Funcionario`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101) e não [é um `Funcionario`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), ou seja, deveria ser uma [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21888/101), até porque quase todo material de OOP ensina isso errado, não posso culpar as pessoas por cometer esse erro. E também porque pode ter casos que essa herança pode ser sim adequada, só não costuma ser em quase tudo que as pessoas fazem, especialmente as menos experientes.

Nem vou falar que [algo que exibe em um dispositivo específico não deveria fazer parte de um objeto que tem por objetivo guardar estado do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) e não manipular o console, ou web, ou GUI, ou lidar com o DB, ou comunicar via rede ou outro serviço, ou fazer várias outras coisas que não tem ligação com o que um `Assistente` deve fazer.

Muito menos falarei que [*getters/setters* nem sempre devem ser usados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), apesar de ensinarem fazer isso por aí.

Provavelmente essa pergunta é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101).

O método `exibirDados()` não parece fazer sentido. Por que ele recebe um parâmetro `Funcionario`? Não consigo imaginar. Retire isso e use o `this` que está disponível no método. Algo assim:

```
public void exibirDados() {
    System.out.println("Nome = " + this.getNome() + " Matrícula: " + this.getMatricula());
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ThisOnMethod.java).

Corrigi outros erros.

Muito provavelmente este método em `Funcionário` está errado também (confirmado depois da edição da pergunta) e precisa consertar, até para manter o [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) tendo a mesma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

Se mantiver o parâmetro em cada método, mas adaptando para o tipo da própria classe em vez de manter o da classe base, como está agora, perderá o [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/303542/101) porque o método passa ser outro.

Reforço para ler todos os *links*. Justamente por pular etapas é que as pessoas aprendem errado. E só os *links* não são suficientes.

- [Herança em programação orientada a objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263289/101)
- [Herança, polimorfismo e acesso à métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286471/101)
- [Por que um método que usa polimorfismo está sendo chamado no lugar de outro em caso de herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410611/101)

Comment: olá, primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta, estudarei sim pelos links. vou complementar aqui a questão.

Comment: coloquei o código na questão, expliquei por que julgo precisar receber o parâmetro Funcionário. Queria também salientar que achei interessante essas visões sobre como o conteúdo de OOP é ensinado, mas destaco aqui que eu preciso resolver essa questão com herança e polimorfismo.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void exibirDados(Funcionario funcionario) {
    System.out.println("Nome = "+ funcionario.getNome()+" Matrícula: "+ funcionario.getMatricula)
}
```

Dentro desse método você recebe um funcionário e ele não tem esse método getMatricula, quem tem é o assistente. Quando você utiliza herança o assistente herda de funcionário, mas não ao contrario, então ele não vai reconhecer que funcionário tem o método getMatricula.

Comment: então esse método deve ser implementado na classe Funcionário mesmo? tinha pensando rapidamente nisso mas achei meio estranho a implementação de um método referente a um atributo de Assistente ser feita em Funcionário, mas vou fazer a mudança e ver se dá bom viu! Obrigado :D!

Comment: Você pode ou adicionar o método dentro da classse funcionário ou só trocar o tipo para assistente, pois ele vai ter acesso aos mesmos gets e sets que já existem la dentro de funcionário e também ao matricula.